# AWS Machine Learning Retrain Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-machine-learning

I have some Models created in AWS Machine Learning with a S3 csv file.
After a lot of search I didn't find the better way to retrain my model.

I would like to know if there any any option to retrain my models with new data or I if need to create a new one each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon ML is providing a set of API (and SDKs) that allows creating programmatically a pipeline that will take new data from S3 and generate the datasource and the ML models from it.

All the components including datasources, ML models, evaluation etc. are **immutable**, and if you want to retrain, you need to recreate it. It allows you to roll back to a previous model, if the performance of the new model is not better that the old model.

Comment: do u have any reference link to understand the flow and try out.